# Accessing a service IP of a service inside a consul service mesh

Tags: kubernetes, networking, consul, hashicorp, servicemesh

Cansomeone help with Consul Service Mesh help me understanding this query please mentioned here

https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/getting-empty-reply-when-accessing-a-pod-ip-which-has-consul-sidecar-containers/32389/2

```
k get pod -o wide -n consul-k8s
```

counting-d9d58c4cb-fr5cr                                      2/2     Running   0              33h   10.288.0.157

Now if do curl as below with Pod IP

```
k exec network-toolspod-f64c586f4-7nzrd --curl 10.288.0.157:9001/counting
```

> % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time
> Current
> Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:--
> --:--:--     0 curl: (52) Empty reply from server command terminated with exit code 52

The same curl command works as expected giving response if there are no consul sidecar containers present along with the deployment by using annotation ‘consul.hashicorp.com/connect-inject’: ‘true’ . Can someone throw some light on this and help me understand this please

Comment: Please type the full question here.

Comment: @Sam thanks, I have edited the question here with my query.

Comment: @Sam any thoughts on this please ?

Comment: Have you configured a sidecar to be injected for both the downstream and upstream service? Are ACLs enabled in your cluster? If so, have you created an Intention to allow access between these two services?